# closest point function modification

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have a function that, given a list of x,y pairs, will calculate the minimum distance between any of the two pairs in the list and return that distance. I would like to modify the code below so that instead of returning the distance itself, it returns the two pairs that yielded that minimum distance in the same order as they were in the input list. For example, if the given input list was [(1, 2), (4, 5), (5, 5), (4, 1)] the resulting output would be ((4, 5), (5, 5)).

```py
import math
#distance function
def distance(p1, p2):
    return math.sqrt((p1[0] - p2[0])**2+(p1[0] - p2[0])**2)

def closest_neighbor(point_list):

    if(len(point_list) < 2):
       return None
    else:
       dist = []

       for i in range(len(point_list) - 1):
          for j in range(i +1, len(point_list)):
          x = point_list[i]
          y = point_list[j]
          dist += [distance(point_list[i], point_list[j])]
   return dist
```

Comment: Store the X and Y coordinates along with the dist. Then, when you would return the distance, return those coordinates instead.

Comment: Currently your distance function is wrong, and the code does not return the minimum of those (wrong) distances either

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
#distance function
def distance(p1, p2):
    return math.sqrt((p1[0] - p2[0])**2+(p1[1] - p2[1])**2) # the original function was wrong

def closest_neighbor(point_list):

    if(len(point_list) < 2):
        return None
    else:
        min = -1
        pair = []

        for i in range(len(point_list) - 1):
            for j in range(i +1, len(point_list)):
                x = point_list[i]
                y = point_list[j]
                dist = distance(point_list[i], point_list[j]) # this could be changed to distance(x,y)
                if dist < min or min == -1:
                    pair = [x,y] # store the pair with min distance
                    min = dist # store the min distance to later comparison
    return pair

print(closest_neighbor( [(1, 2), (4, 5), (5, 5), (4, 1)]))
```

Comment: a little detail: since we want the pair with minimum distance and not the minimum distance, we could remove the sqrt function because doesn't make difference in the final result and avoid useless calculations. :)

Comment: You could use `enumerate` in your loops and avoid both the `x =` and `y =` lookups.  (Also, your indentation is currently bad!)

Comment: So i tried your solution and I am currently getting a type error on the line where I compare dist and min due to '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Comment: I think that you tried just a piece of code. Copy the whole code in the answer and try it. And by the way, I noticed an indentation error, but I edited now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you fix your currently incorrect distance function, then it is as simple as:

```
>>> min( (distance(x, y), (x, y)) for x, y in itertools.combinations(point_list, 2))[1]
((4, 5), (5, 5))
```

Here we generate all combinations of two points from the list, calculate their distance, and take advantage of the fact that tuples sort element-wise.

(You will need to add a check for the length of `point_list` if that is important to you)

Comment: Your code shows a deep knowledge about python and it is very interesting, but the question was about how to modify the current code to get the desired result. Maybe small modifications was a better answer. But anyway, this is just a bike shed.